# Configure maven on linux for android in eclipse

Tags: android, maven, ubuntu, path

I am following the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted in order to use maven with my android projects (I am learning android). I am stuck at the steps:

- Set environment variable ANDROID_HOME to the path of your installed Android SDK and add $ANDROID_HOME/tools as well as $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to your $PATH. (or on Windows %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools).

Will someone please show me how to complete that step?

I am using linux `Natty Narwhal` and eclipse `juno` to test the samples. The path to my `Android SDK` is `/home/myusr/opt/android-sdk-linux`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the following to your `/etc/profile` file (at the end of the file) or you can do it just for your user editing `/home/your_user/.bashrc`:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/myusr/opt/android-sdk-linux
export ANDROID_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH
```

Logout/Login from your shell. You can verify the result with:

```
printenv
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I edited the file and restarted the terminal. But when I tried `printenv`, I didn't see `/home/myusr/opt/android-sdk-linux` anywhere in the printout. Is that line what I am expecting?

Comment: how did you edited the file? keep in mind you should do it as sudo user.

Comment: yes, I did. And when I `vim` into the file, I see the edits. They just don't show for `printenv`.

Comment: checkout this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables It seems the /etc/profile is not recommended (though it should work, cause I use this approach in couple of environments); try to go with some of the other suggested files.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I type the following directly in the terminal and that seems to work: `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/myusr/opt/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: yes, but that will be valid only for the current session. You probably want to make it permanent, otherwise you will have to type it every time... It really should work for any of the files that are mentioned in the linked article.